# how to add font in scss preprocessor?

Tags: sass

I am adding a custom font in my project when I am adding this font using normal CSS that time it's working but when I am using this font in SCSS processor CSS that time it's not working.

I am sharing the screen shot of file and console error.

I do not find where I am doing wrong. Please resolve my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post the code and not the image.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your suggestion @Alien

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty much self-explanatory. The issue is you are using `=` instead of a `:` to assign the value to the variable. It should be

```
$roboto-Regular: 'robotoregular';
```

---

Don't be so specific with the variable names, variables are meant to hold dynamic data. If tomorrow, you change the font to some other font, using `roboto-Regular` as the variable name would make no sense. You should use something like

```
$base-font: 'robotoregular';
$fallback-font: 'Arial';

font-family: $base-font, $fallback-font;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alien, I miss it.